# 14MB Increase in Memory Usage - Bringing up Keyboard - iPad Retina

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-management, ios7, uikit

I've noticed something strange running an app on a retina iPad under iOS7.

Bringing up the standard keyboard (via the user tapping in a UITextfield) sees a memory spike of 14MB in the Activity Monitor in Instruments, whereas on a non-retina iPad this is around 4MB.

Is this to be expected /normal or should I be checking my code ?

Comment: Use Instruments to see what's using the memory.

Comment: The dreaded cgrasterdata....what is this?